# Why PHP runs very slow over apache server

Tags: php, performance, loading, apache

I am having a bit performance problem with my PHP pages.  My application is combined of two different languages, PHP and JSP which are using apache and tomcat on top. My JSPs are very fast but php pages are like 10 times slower and their both using the same database too. I know JAVA supposed to be faster than PHP but my application is running extremely slow on PHP section BUT not on JSPs.

Also, I am 100% sure nothing is wrong with my PHP scripts but it looks like it is apache that takes long to process php and some static files. Please let me know if anyone has ever came across such problem. I don't mind posting my apache conf file if you need to have a look at it.

**Note:** Apache is configured to serve all the files apart from Servlets/JSPs and the JSPs are running faster even than some htmls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be interesting to know what exactly do those php pages do? it's not about the technology but the 'things' that the script is doing (e.g. using cURL, processing a huge chunk of text, etc) that can slow things down.

Comment: I dont think PHP is slower than JAVA in general cases [until it's huge]

Comment: Are you talking about 10ms vs. 100ms or 1 sec vs. 10 sec? Are both pages doing the exact same thing?

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I tried to run the page even without any script, just an empty php page but it still takes like 10 times more time to load compare to JSPs.  The whole application is on my development server which unfortunately has no external links yet until 30th of this month but have a look at the php section site of www.facejar.com which is the section that takes ages to load.

Comment: Sourav, I think Java is faster than PHP because its already in bytecode and php has to be compiled each time you loading.  Yes deceze, its kind of doing the same job.

Comment: Sailab you can cache your PHP files to bytecode if you think that is the case.

Comment: if html files are also serving slow then it's not phps fault

Comment: Yes that is what I am complaining about.  It looks like something to do with my apache configuration. You see all those JSPs are served by Tomcat on the same machine with the help of mode JK but php and other statics are served by apache.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by caching it to bytecode. Few lines of source might help me if you have some.

Answer (score 1):

- For PHP use some kind of opcode cache like [APC](https://www.php.net/apc) or [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/) otherwise PHP has to parse your files on each request.
- For general apache tuning you should do some googling, couple of things like disabling `.htaccess` files comes to mind but it still should be faster than JSP... Some [apache performance tuning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html) tips.